# how to print infinity symbol in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to set an NSString with infinity symbol '∞' and print it onto the screen. I don't know how to make it. Hope you guys could help.

Comment: Just be aware that not all terminals will be able to properly display symbols.

Comment: @mah - Yep, it will almost certainly not display properly in an NSLog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `NSString *infinity = @"\u221E";`

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x221E];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the ASCII code and then create an NSString object.

Something like this:

```
int code = 236; //I believe this is the code you are looking for.
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", code];
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: the result loooks like `i` + ` symbol